# Openmp nested parallelism use available threads

Tags: fortran, openmp, fftw

So, I have this simple Fortran do loop and inside that loop a couple of subroutines are called. I have 
Made the do loop parallel with OpenMP, like this

```
    !$omp parallel do
    do i=1,n
        call a()
        call b()
    enddo
    !$omp end parallel do
```

Now most of the times the number of iterations in the loop is 
less compared to the number of processor/threads available and the subroutines that are called inside the 
loop can be called in parallel. So, is there a way to call the subroutines in parallel inside the parallel 
do loop ? I have tried with `task` like this

```
    !$omp parallel do
    do i=1,n
        !$omp task
        call a(i , j )
        !$omp end    task
        !$omp task
        call b(i, k)
        !$omp end task
        !$omp taskwait
    enddo
    !$omp end parallel do
```

But this shows some error with `segmentation fault`. Is there any way to achieve this.

### UPDATE:

So, I found out the main reason for the segmentation fault is coming from the fftw library. Lets consider a dummy program

```
program name
    !$use omp_lib
    implicit real*8(a-h,p-z)
    call system_clock(count_rate=irate)
    call system_clock(it1)
    !$ call omp_set_nested(.true.)
    !$omp parallel do 
    do i =1,5
        call test(i)
        print *, i
    enddo
    !$omp end parallel do 
    call system_clock(it2)
    print *, (it2-it1)/real(irate, kind=8)
end program name


subroutine test(ii)
    ! just a dummy subroutine for heavy computation
    implicit real*8(a-h,p-z)
        do j=1,40000
            !$omp task
            do k=1,40000
                x = exp(sqrt(sqrt(2.0d0*ii**3)**2))
            enddo
            !$omp end task
        enddo
end subroutine
```

This program works exactly what I wants and using the task directives, uses the remaining threads and improves the performance. Now lets consider another dummy program but with fftw, similar to what I'm working.

```
program name
    !$use omp_lib
    implicit real*8(a-h,p-z)
    integer, parameter :: n=8192*8
    complex(kind=8) :: arr(n)
    real(kind=8) :: tmp1(n), tmp2(n)
    integer(kind=8) :: pF
    integer :: i

    call system_clock(count_rate=irate)
    call dfftw_plan_dft_1d(pF,n,arr,arr,-1,0) ! forward
    call system_clock(it1)

    !$ call omp_set_nested(.true.)
    !$omp parallel do private(arr)
    do i =1,5
        call random_number(tmp1)
        call random_number(tmp2)
        arr = cmplx(tmp1, tmp2, kind=8)
        call test(pF, arr)
        print *, i
    enddo
    !$omp end parallel do 
    call system_clock(it2)

    print *, (it2-it1)/real(irate, kind=8)

end program name


subroutine test(pF, arr)
    implicit real*8(a-h,p-z)
    complex(kind=8) :: arr(:)
    integer(kind=8) :: pF
    do j=1,100
        !$omp task private(arr)
        do k=1, 100
            call dfftw_execute_dft(pF, arr, arr)
        enddo
        !$omp end task
    enddo
end subroutine
```

Now, this throws the segmentation fault. (NOTE: I have no random numer call in my actual program, they are here just for a dummy purpose). I have checked http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Thread-safety.html and `fftw_execute` is thread safe and the program works without the `task` directives. But with the `task` it throws error. Anyone knows how to fix this ?

Comment: All examples I can find involve `$omp parallel` and `$omp single` around the task clauses. Have you tried that? I would start by getting it to work without the outer parallel loop. Once you got that down, add back the outer loop and enable nested parallelism in OpenMP and it should work as expected.

Comment: "*some* error with `segmentation fault`" If you are interested about the explanation for the error, you will have to show more, otherwise we can tell you that you have *some* problem in your code. Did you enable nested parallelism? How? Shouln't the tasks be enough? Why wouldn't you remove the `parallel do` altogether?

Comment: I have updated the question with new details, please check.

Comment: Please fix implicit real*8 and kind=8, they are anathemae to good, modern Fortran practice. WHERE does it seg fault? And why do you have private( arr ) on the task?

Answer (score 1):

Sigh, yet another example of why `!$omp do parallel` is a bad idea ... I really do think it is best to clearly separate the thread creation and worksharing phases.

As Vladimir says in the comments you haven't provided nearly enough detail to tell why you are getting a segmentation fault. However you seem to have a few misconceptions about OpenMP which I can try to address.

Firstly a very quick and dirty way to achieve what you want and avoiding any extra OpenMP directives is

```
!$omp parallel default( none ) private( i ) shared( n ) ! Create threads
!$omp do                                                ! Now share out the work
Do i = 1, 2 * n
   If( Mod( i, 2 ) == 1 ) Then
     Call a
   Else
     Call b
End Do
!$omp end do
!$omp end parallel
```

However if you want to use tasks you're probably not doing it the easiest way if all calls to a and b are completely independent. In that case remember that a new task is created whenever ANY thread hits a `!$omp task`, and that that task can be executed by any thread, not just the one that created it. Following that logic something like

```
!$omp parallel default( none ) private( i ) shared( n ) ! Crate the threads
!$omp single
Do i = 1, n
   !$omp task
   Call a
   !$omp end task
   !$omp task
   call b
   !$omp end task
end do
!$omp end single
!$omp end parallel
```

is what you want - you use one thread to create the list of tasks, and then (or more probably while the list is being created) all the available threads will execute them, each task being taken by the next available thread. Note I have also missed out the taskwait directive as from your description I'm not sure why you think you need it as I can see no need for synchronisation at that point.

Comment: I have updated the question with new details, please check.